# What do I lose by putting crappie nibbles on everything?

Tags: fishing

Lately, I've been sticking crappie nibbles on the hook of almost anything I toss into the water, from trout magnets to marabou jigs to swim shads to inline spinners.

Am I losing anything by doing so?

For example, I sometimes worry that the pink or chartreuse nibbles interfere with the action of the crankbaits and soft plastics, or that they make more subtle lures too visible. But that hasn't stopped me yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't realized it yet, there is no such thing as "the right bait/lure" until you have a fish bite it.

I have used what was supposedly "the right bait" for a certain spot and got skunked until I stuck something completely different on my line. I have had fish chase and eat my **bare hook**. I have had fish attack the most ungodly contraptions that have ever been cast, and ignore the most expensive lure in my tackle box.

The only thing that matters is if fish bite what you offer, and the only way to make that happen is to experiment. If you stick crappie nibbles on everything and you don't catch any fish, that is the fish telling you they don't like it. If you keep doing that and keep getting skunked, you are less smart than you could be. If you stick crappie nibbles on lures and catch fish, you are a badass fish-catching genius.

Comment: This is obviously the right answer, since it involves me being a "badass fish-catching genius."

I pulled in fifty fish this weekend (and probably burned through 100 crappie nibbles) though I still wonder if I'm leaving some bites on the table by not relying on the unencumbered "action" of my lures.